# IsolatedStorage.GetFileNames fails on MonoTouch/MonoDroid

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, isolatedstorage

I was trying out MonoTouch/MonoAndroid and everything was going
well until I called IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames(string) function. The
parameter was "Foo/Foo1/*". The result is SecurityException with no message.

The directory "Foo/Foo1" exists, because it has just been found using IsolatedStorageFile.GetDirectoryNames() call.

I identified this bit in Mono sources that throws the exception (in IsolatedStorageFile.cs):

```
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = directory.GetDirectories (path);
// we're looking for a single result, identical to path (no pattern here)
// we're also looking for something under the current path (not
outside isolated storage)
if ((subdirs.Length == 1) && (subdirs [0].Name == path) && (subdirs[0].FullName.IndexOf(directory.FullName) >= 0)) {
  afi = subdirs [0].GetFiles (pattern);
} else {
  // CAS, even in FullTrust, normally enforce IsolatedStorage
  throw new SecurityException ();
}
```

I can't step into it with the debugger so I don't know why the
condition is false. This happens both on iOS and Android. There was a
similar issue logged long time ago at
http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/12492/1724/#post1724, but there
are no replies.

The same code works on Windows Phone 7 without problems (with \ for path separators).

Has anyone got any ideas what might be causing it? Is it the uppercase in
directory names a problem?

Comment: After a bit searching I have some questions for you. Do you have fast deployment enabled? There has been some issues with that before making the folders have incorrect permissions: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/IsolatedStorage-or-OpenFileOutput-td5116430.html Also are you sure you want to use the internal memory of the device? This is usually only used for caching small amounts of data. Larger stuff should go on the SDcard. IsolatedStorage only points at the Internal memory of the phone.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I don't know about fastdeployment, I will have to check it when I get a chance later today. Do you think it may be causing the exception?

Comment: It has been seen before to do that, due to wrong permissions on the created folders for the application. A solution is to remove the application from the device, disable fast deployment and try again. See if that helps.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Hmm, there is no fast deployment option in MonoTouch but it fails in the same way as Mono For Android. I have a feeling this is not the cause... I will try to disable it in Mono For Android.

Comment: Found the problem - unfortunately this is a bug in Mono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in Mono. IsolatedStorage will not work with paths that contain more than one directory in a row (such as Foo/Foo1/*)

I copied the code of GetFileNames() method from Mono to my project so that I can debug it. I found out that the problem is in the 2nd term of this condition (IsolatedStorageFile.cs:846):

```
if ((subdirs.Length == 1) && (subdirs [0].Name == path) &&(subdirs[0].FullName.IndexOf(directory.FullName) >= 0)) {
  afi = subdirs [0].GetFiles (pattern);
} else {
  // CAS, even in FullTrust, normally enforce IsolatedStorage
  throw new SecurityException ();
}
```

For example when path passed to GetFileNames() is "Foo/Bar/*", subdirs[0].Name will be "Bar" while path will be "Foo/Bar" and the condition will fail causing the exception.

Comment: If you have not done it yet, it would be awesome if you filed it as a bug if not already present in the bug tracker: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/